# How to make components wait for Ajax changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I make my components wait for an ajax call to complete before being rendered? Right now, their data objects are empty because the ajax call has not completed when they are mounted.

Additionally, I want all components to have access to this ajax data, which will be refreshed and updated every 30 seconds. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
//Snippet of what gets return from ajax call
{
  121: {
    table_info: {
    id: "121",
    name: "Test",
    table_number: "51",
    cap: "6",
    seating: "OPEN",
    position_x: "0.19297285",
    position_y: "0.07207237",
    participants_in_tables: "5",
    count: 5
   }
 }
}
```

```js
//Global
var tableData; //This gets set when the Vue ajax call is complete after being mounted
var width = $(document).width();
var height = $(document).height();

//Vue
Vue.component('tables', {
      data: () => {
        return {
          tables: tableData
        }
      },
      template: `
                <div id="tableContain">
                    <div class='table' v-for="table in tables" :style="computeOffsets(table)">
                        {{table.table_info.name}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            `,
      methods: {
        computeOffsets(table) {
          return {
            top: (table.table_info.position_x * width) + 'px',
            left: (table.table_info.position_y * height) + 'px'
          }
        }
      });

    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#main',
      mounted() {
        $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          url: base_url + 'users/getTableAssignments/' + event_id
        }).done(data => {
          tableData = data; //Set global tableData 
        });
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use created in vue and then get the data with props in component like:

```
Vue.component('tables', {  
  props: ['tables']  
  // ...
});

var app = new Vue({  
  el: '#main', 
  data: { tables: [] },
  created() { 
    axios.get('url').then( response => { this.tables = response.data } )
  }
});
```

I prefer axios but u can use ajax if u like :D

And if u like to refresh u can just use intervals but I prefer server side solution like sockets. Im using it in my app with laravel broadcasting, redis and sockets to have a realtime dashboard :D

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, the problem is that props:['tables'] passes undefined. I would like for it to wait until ajax is complete before passing data. Or better yet, have the child component watch 'tables" for changes and then update accordingly

Comment: You had to do some mistakes try to debug it with npm run watch. Second part wont work cuss u only once get the data with ajax call. If u want to make it refreshed u need to do another call.

In your HTML File u need to do <tables :tables="tables"></tables>

To pass this props :)